# Excel how to find algebraic curve and fill in estimate?

Tags: excel, algebra

Given a generic "rank" column and some actual data in the `SOLD-LAST-MONTH` column, how can i fill in the blanks using excel's basic algebra functions?

```
SALESRANK   SOLD-LAST-MONTH
171 
433         2931
1104    
1484        2691
1872        2108
2196    
2762        495
2829    
3211    
6646    
7132    
10681   
10804
```

Seems like the numbers on the left would form a curve and the numbers on the right would shape the curve.

I'm forgetting my highschool math days about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fitting a curve requires much more than simple algebra.

Also, you don't have enough data to define a curve. Plotting the points you already have (using x-y scatter plot), the extrapolation from the last 3 points would be the red line, which runs into negatives very quickly.

Sales obviously need to remain positive, so assuming a very small number of sales for the lowest salesrank and plotting that point as well shows what the curve should look more like.

To generate the green curve I just drew a smooth line over the known points. (Using drawing tools and adjusting the points and gradients until the curve looks reasonable. We can do this visually easily but programmatically it's very complicated.)

It would be easiest (and considering how little data you have, it's also about as accurate as you'll get) to just read values from the curve at each salesrank point.

While it's safe to assume sales are near zero at the lowest ranks, the top ranks can be unpredictable... in some situations the top few ranks are far greater than the rest. For a more accurate curve near the top ranks, you really need to know the number of sales for the top rank. That would allow you to get a far more accurate value for the 171 rank.

[image: Img]